# Is it feasible to change the CSS of the Google Doc interface with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-docs

Using Google Apps Script or any other way, is it possible to modify the Google Doc interface to my liking? Is there a way to inject my CSS over Google Doc's own? When I open documents from my site, I would like to modify the Google Doc interface so it looks like my website.

Right now, I've set up a service account and made a website where I can manage a Drive and many Google documents.

Comment: You can change Google Document styles with Google Apps Script.  As for using CSS selectors...I don't think so.

Comment: May be  with a browser add on running scripts client side.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it's possible with a Chrome extension.